# Unable to run netstat,scp command by ssh into into another host in bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to run netstat in two remote hosts; redirect to a file ; then scp the file to the host from where I am running the script. merge the file and send an email based on the output.

but currently scp is not working and also the netstat command cannot be run. However I can run the echo and redirection works in that case.

```
ssh unixaccount@$HOSTNAME1 << EOF

echo "GATEWAY" >> $output2
echo "health check" >> $output2;
netstat -an | grep ESTABLISHED | grep $IPADDRESS:$port >> $output2
echo "health check 2" >> $output2
netstat -an | grep ESTABLISHED | grep $IPADDRESS:$port >> $output2
echo "health check 3" >> $output2
netstat -an | grep ESTABLISHED | grep $IPADDRESS:$port >> $output2
scp $output2 $MASTER_SVR:$output2


EOF

cd /tmp
cat output1 >> output3
cat output2 >> output3

RAG1=`grep "ESTABLISHED" output3| wc -l`

if [$RAG1 -eq 6 ];
then
  mail -s 'GATEWAY connection check - GREEN' emailaddress < $output3;
else
  mail -s 'GATEWAY connection check - RED' emailaddress < $output3;
```

Comment: What is scp error?

Comment: what is $outputfile2 and $output2. are those supposed to be same the file?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. There was typo with $outputfile2. It should be $output2. I have updated , but still get the below error with the scp command : cp: cannot create regular file ':/tmp/output1': No such file or directory

Comment: It appears to me scp is not running in the remote host and rather in the local host due to which it refers to cp command. The issue is ssh to remote host and running netstat/scp is not working